# Grails command object and 404 when space inside JSON from CURL

Tags: json, grails, curl, command-objects

I have inherited a controller. 
When a post request is made, with a well structured JSON document everything is fine.

When the JSON contains a space in a feld, 404 is returned.
However, when the same request is made from mozilla restclient extension everything works.

The CURL request specifically is:

```
curl --include \
     --request POST \
     --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
     --header "Accept: application/json" \
     --data-binary "{
        "planCode" : "My Test App-standard"
    }" \
     "https://localhost/signupApi/v2/signup"
```

URLMapping:

```
  "/signupApi/v2/$action"{
        parseRequest = true // parse json, and assign to params
        controller = "signupApiSignup"
    }
```

So, why would a space in curl cause problems in the request body that grails receives?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not quoting your strings there properly in your shell.  Use `'` for your parameters, if you plan to use "sensitive" chars like `"` there.  Or use `\"` inside.  Also curl can read a filename if you prefix it with `@` instead of the actual data.

Yet in this case maybe quoting with `'` is easiest. E.g.:

```
 ...
 --data-binary '{
    "planCode" : "My Test App-standard"
 }'
 ...
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick! Will accept once time limit passes.